# hibernate detached criteria - How to add a native sql statement

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, detachedcriteria

Hi I have very big problem. I have a DetachedCriteria and I named it `dc`. I declared it this way `DetachedCriteria dc = getDetachedCriteria()`. I want to add a collation statement before the order by. The purpose of collation is to handle `ñ`. The statement I want to add is `COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci`.  I did it this way `dc.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(" COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci "))`. Of course I got an error because this is wrong. I don't know to do it. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute native SQL queries in order to take advantage of your particular database features, this is how is done in hibernate using detached criteria...

```
List<YourEntity> list = (List<YourEntity>) yourEntityDAO.getHibernateTemplate().execute(
    new HibernateCallback() {
    @Override
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
        SQLQuery sq = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE");
        return sq.addEntity(YourEntity.class).list();
    }
});
```